# when press submit the page reloading as the php file

Tags: php, html

I have some problem with my form...
When I press the submit button the page not only doesn't send the mail, it also reloading the page and show the php file at a text all over the website... Someone know how to fix that please?
Thank you all!

The form part from the HTML:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" width="50%">
                                <div class="cart-total">
                                    <strong class="cart-total-title">סך הכל</strong>
                                    <span class="cart-total-price">0₪</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="25%">
                                <input type="text" name="inpPhone" size="10" required></input>
                                :טלפון
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="25%">
                                <input type="text" name="inpName" size="10" required></input>
                                :שם מלא
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" width="25%">
                                <input type="text" name="inpCity" size="10" required></input>
                                :עיר
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="25%">
                                <input type="text" name="inpAddress" size="10" required></input>
                                :כתובת
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right">
                                <input type="date" name="inpDate" required></input>
                                :תאריך אספקה (ניתן להזמין עד יומיים לפני)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right">
                                </br>
                                אם הוזמנו מארז עוגיות/עוגת שמרים, יווצר עמך קשר בהמשך לגבי בחירת עוגיות/עוגה *
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" name="submit">להזמנה</button>
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset(_POST['submit'])) {
    $subject = "הזמנה חדשה";
    $name = $_POST['inpName'];
    $phone = $_POST['inpPhone'];
    $city = $_POST['inpCity'];
    $address = $_POST['inpAddress'];

    $mailTo = "sappati@outlook.com";
    $headers = "From:".$name;
    $txt =
        "התקבלה הזמנה חדשה! אלו פרטי ההזמנה:\n".
        "שם: ".$name."\n".
        "טלפון: ".$phone."\n".
        "עיר: ".$city."\n".
        "כתובת: ".$address."\n";

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: This is just how html buttons work with PHP. If you want to avoid reloading a webpage on a POST request you can use AJAX. Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: ok so ill try it, but also do you know maybe why the email is not sending when i press the button?

Comment: Is your PHP code in a 'mail.php' file?

Comment: yes, the mail.php file is the function file

Comment: Did you look at the answer provided by Tiko, is your server setup correctly? Or are you running on a local environment?

Answer (score 0):

It's the native behavior of server side languages to reload to handle the request, if you want to make requests to server side, then you should use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or any other library for making requests

And about the php file being served as text, you should have apache or any other server install on your local machine to be able to handle server side code